# Geolocator Plugin to get current location

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I am using `Geolocator` plugin to get the current location of the device, and google map plugin to integrate the map widget in the flutter

The google map works fine, but the `Geolocator` it gives me this error:

```
D/permissions_handler(10148): No permissions found in manifest for: $permission
D/permissions_handler(10148): No permissions found in manifest for: $permission
```

and the error still appears, any idea of why this happening?

And in the file `Androidmanifest.xml` I added these permissions inside

```
<manifest>:
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you have these permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file located at `android/app/src/main` directory?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, and the weird I test it using another Laptop and it works, But in myPc is not working it asks for permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is google_maps_flutter package needs permission for accessing your location but the package has not native codes to ask that permission.

So you need to write native code or just install another package which is able to take that permission.

Install this: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location

Then:

```
getLocationPermission() async {
    final Location location = new Location();
    try {
      location.requestPermission(); //to lunch location permission popup
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        print('Permission denied');
      }
    }
  }
```

Or if you want more solid code, this is my code for some project(with location package):

```
//Show some loading indicator depends on this boolean variable
bool askingPermission = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    this.getLocationPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getLocationPermission() async {
    setState(() {
      this.askingPermission = true;
    });
    bool result;
    final Location location = Location();
    try {
      if (await location.hasPermission())
        result = true;
      else {
        result = await location.requestPermission();
      }
      print('getLocationPermission: '
          '${result ? 'Access Allowed' : 'Access Denied'}');
    } catch (log, trace) {
      result = false;
      print('getLocationPermission/log: $log');
      print('getLocationPermission/trace: $trace');
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        this.askingPermission = false;
      });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

add this package into flutter project..
- pubspec.yaml

-dependencies:

```
  location: ^2.3.4
```

Comment: it give the same thing as above

Comment: android studio restart again using invalidcatch/restart option