# Turn on GPS using Flutter

Tags: flutter, location

There is a prompt box which tells user to Turn on GPS. But seems like I can not find the code which opens the pop-up box.

I do not need access_settings_menu. As I can say there is an option which turns on GPS of an android set. The below image from Uber App. When I press the button it pops up a box which lets user turn on GPS. They need not to visit access_settings_menu.

Button

[image: button]

pop up box

[image: pop up]

(Can not upload image here. my apologies)

I want to achieve this in Flutter. I already can get this box which lets a user to turn on GPS but seems like I can not find out the code which pops up the box.

Answer (score 4):

Using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) lib from **pub.dev** you can find the desired solution. Here is also a sample code.

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;

loc.Location locationR = loc.Location();

if (!await locationR.serviceEnabled()) {
  locationR.requestService();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In IOS, it's handled automatically when application needs to access GPS. But in Android, you need to use a package or write native code.

For my detailed answer:
[Geolocator Plugin to get current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628060/geolocator-plugin-to-get-current-location/55632631#55632631)

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is, don't forget the close the issue through accepting the answer.

Comment: I have not tested your full code yet. I have partially implemented it. I will let you know. Thanks.